# Web Speech API lag time -- how fix?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, webspeech-api

I am using the Web Speech API in a web page. However, I am finding that it takes 3-5 seconds to bring back a result, which is a lot of lag time in today's web world. Has anyone else had this problem? Has anyone found a solution?

Here's the barebones of what I have so far -- it works, per se, but I need it to be faster.

```
var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();        
    recognition.lang = 'en-US';
    recognition.onresult = function(evt) {
        console.log(evt);
};
recognition.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't a network speed issue, using

```
recognition.continuous = false;
```

will get a faster result (with some caveats)

see my detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25414548/1363)